# GWT app throws exception when client in debug mode

Tags: gwt

If I launch the URL [code]http://localhost:8888/app1.html?[/code] and click a button it works fine. Calls into my RPC on localhost fine.  However if I then change the URL so the client is in debug mode ie 
[code]http://localhost:8888/app1.html?gwt.codesvr=localhost:[/code]it then throws an exception at the point where it calls into the RPC service on my local server.

Here is the exception code.

```java
08:08:41.482 [ERROR] [nquizitive] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.&lt;init&gt;(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doCreateRequestCallback(RemoteServiceProxy.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doPrepareRequestBuilderImpl(RemoteServiceProxy.java:433)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doInvoke(RemoteServiceProxy.java:368)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy$ServiceHelper.finish(RemoteServiceProxy.java:74)
    at com.app.nquizitive.client.service.CategoryService_Proxy.createCategory(CategoryService_Proxy.java:32)
    at com.app.nquizitive.client.presenter.HomeViewPresenter$2.onClick(HomeViewPresenter.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The line that causes the issue is the callinto the category service.

```java
public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
    display.getNewCategoryName();
    categoryService.createCategory( display.getNewCategoryName(), null )
}
```

Just noticed that I get the exception because the Async callback is null.  Can I not set it to null if i am not interested in the response.  This is basically a fire and forget call.

Here is the code that works

```java
public void onClick(ClickEvent event){

     display.getNewCategoryName();
     categoryService.createCategory( display.getNewCategoryName(), new AsyncCallback(){

         public void onFailure(Throwable caught){
             Window.alert("Error fetching categorys");
         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess(Object result){
             //New Category added so update display
             fetchCategorys();
         }

     });
}
```

Still don't understand why a null Async callback object works in run mode :(

Comment: Are you mentioning issue w.r.t SuperDevMode. Otherwise i am not sure how http://localhost:8888/app1.html works!!!!

Comment: check and debug code HomeViewPresenter.java line no:60. throw null pointer error.

Comment: Yes,  at line 60 is where it throws the exception.  But why it only throws it in debug mode is what is bugging me.  I have put my code up on OP

Comment: I have actually found that because the Async callback is null causes the problem but why does it work in run mode and not in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't fail in prod mode is that this is an assertion (`assert callback != null`), and assertions are disabled by default in prod mode.

Given that there's no code that checks whether the callback is null before calling `onSuccess` or `onFailure` on it (because, you know, we already asserted it was non-null), I'd bet it actually **does** fail in prod mode: if you look at the JS console in your browser you should see an error such as *cannot call method 'xxx' of null*. If you had a `GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler` it would have been called back with that error.

Comment: yea,  that was it.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you see in your debug configuration arguments tab

```
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl index.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -war E:\workspace
```

There sould be a `codeServerPort`  port 9997 for remote Ui server port ..So you have to give your url like below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/app1.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

You can change the port in eclipse debug config .